# What is the expl3 equivalent of \AddToHook?

Tags: expl3, hooks

While writing a package, when encountering commands like `\selectlanguage` that do not work inside the preamble, I've learned to put them inside `\AddToHook{begindocument}{...}`, so that if it is called in preamble, it will automatically be delayed to the beginning of the document.

For packages written with expl3, I've been (mistakenly) using `\hook_gput_next_code:nn` as its equivalent form. However, I just realized that they are not the same. For example, with the following code, `text in document 2` won't show up.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\AddToHook { begindocument } { text in preamble 1 \\ }
\hook_gput_next_code:nn { begindocument } { text in preamble 2 \\ }

\begin{document}

\AddToHook { begindocument } { text in document 1 }\\
\hook_gput_next_code:nn { begindocument } { text in document 2 }

\end{document}
```

Looking into `texdoc lthooks`, it seems that `\hook_gput_next_code:nn` is the only one with `:nn` specifier that seems close to `\AddToHook`. What is the actual expl3-equivalent of `\AddToHook`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `\hook_gput_code:nnn`. At the `expl3` level, there is no 'label guessing': you *have* to specify what label is used. This contrasts to the design-level `\AddToHook`, which will assume it can use the name of the file, unless you add the optional argument.

Comment: `\AddToHook{x}{code}` is equivalent to `\hook_gput_code:nnn {x}{.}{code}`: the `.` is replaced by the current `<default label>`, which is the current package name, or `top-level`.